# CSS Works In IE8 With Linux/Apache2.0/PHP4 But Not With Windows/IIS7/PHP5

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I just changed from a linux/apache2.0/php4 web server to a windows/iis7/php5 web server (I only post php versions since that was a significant change).

My css is working just fine on the linux one (http://66.119.8.165/flcunderconstruction.php) but it isn't working on the windows one (http://66.119.8.236/flcunderconstruction.php).

Now, the issue only seems to be applicable to internet explorer 8 (maybe older, but I'm not testing those).  Firefox and internet explorer 9 work just fine.

I think I've ruled out php issues as I created a non-php version (http://66.119.8.236/flcunderconstruction.html) and the issue persists.

I'm assuming the problem is in the css (which is quite large and throws up a lot of validation errors).  But since it only occurs on the windows server and with ie8, I'm hesitant to start whacking away at the code.

Any ideas?

JJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The broken version stops loading when it hits /include/html5.js. You only see this on IE8 because later versions handle the HTML5 stuff just fine without the polyfill.

- Missing: http://66.119.8.236/include/html5.js
- Present: http://66.119.8.165/include/html5.js

To test this, press F12 to open up the Developer Tools. Switch your Browser Mode to IE8. Jump over to your Network tab and press "Start Capturing". Perform a hard refresh (CTRL+F5), and watch as the files begin loading in. You'll note the 404 when it gets to the HTML5 polyfill. (Image below)

Using [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), I set up and Auto Responder to automatically add the HTML5 file from my local machine in the place of your missing file. Refreshing the request resulted in the entire site loading as expected in IE8. Put your polyfill on the other server, and you should be set.

[image]

Comment: That is wonderful.  I didn't realize the power of F12.  Now that I've seen the problem, I remember deleting that file.  I thought it was being loaded from the internet but it was actually html5media (http://www.html5media.info) on a different page that loaded remotely.